# LWC Datatable (NOT AURA) infinite scrolling not working - loadmoredata is being called multiple time

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable

I have added height and to the outer div but its not working still

```
 <div style="height: 900px;border:1px solid rgb(221, 219, 218)" class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-1">
        <lightning-datatable
                key-field="id"
                data={data}
                columns={columns}
                onrowselection={getSelectedName}
                enable-infinite-loading={enableInfiniteLoading}
                show-row-number-column
                hide-checkbox-column
                onloadmore={loadMoreData}
                onrowaction={handleRowAction}
                is-loading={tableLoadingState}
                onsave={handleSave}
                draft-values={draftValues}
                onsort={updateColumnSorting}
                sorted-by={sortBy}
                sorted-direction={sortDirection}
                column-widths-mode="auto"
                min-column-width=120
                >
        </lightning-datatable>

      <!--  {loadMoreStatus} -->
    </div>  





loadMoreData(event) {
        const { target } = event;
        //Display a spinner to signal that data is being loaded
        target.isLoading = true;

        this.queryOffset = this.queryOffset + this.queryLimit;
        initRecords({ ObjectName: this.objectApiName, fieldNamesStr: this.fieldNamesStr,nameField:this.nameField,relatedFieldName: this.relatedFieldName, recordId: this.recordId ,
             Orderby: this.sortBy, OrderDir: this.sortDirection,inlineEdit:this.inlineEdit , enableColAction:this.colAction, queryLimit:this.queryLimit, 
             queryOffset:this.queryOffset, otherFilterSOQLString:this.otherFilterSOQLString  })
        .then(result => {
            const currentData = this.addNameUrlValue(result.sobList);
            //add nameurl field 
            //Appends new data to the end of the table
            const newData = currentRecord.concat(currentData);
            this.data = newData; 
            

           target.isLoading = false;
            if (this.data.length >= this.totalNumberOfRows) {
                this.enableInfiniteLoading=false;
                this.loadMoreStatus = 'No more data to load';
            } else {
                this.loadMoreStatus = '';
            }
        })
        .catch(error => {
            target.isLoading = false;
            console.log('-------error-------------'+error);
            console.log(error);
        });
    }
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on `its not working still`? I have it working just fine in multiple orgs

Comment: @zaitsman When I scroll down, loadmoredata is called infinite number of times

Comment: that is literally the definition of `infinite` scrolling :)))) why would it ever stop?

Comment: When I scroll down once it should call loadmoredata only once, if I scroll down again then second time ...

Comment: something is amiss. you are saying you scroll once and then your method is called in a loop? that is not what i'm seeing at all. 99% there is a bug in your `loadMoreData`

Comment: updated question with loadMoreData method

Comment: Just add `if (target.isLoading) { return; }` to the first line of that method

Comment: @zaitsman Thank you. That prevented it and the wired method for initial data load is getting called multiple times as well, so we added check there as well